# How to parse ReferenceError object from window.onerror (5th parameter, implemented in Google Chrome)

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome

I am logging js errors from console with

```
window.onerror = function (errorMsg, url, lineNumber, column, errorObj)
```

Want to `JSON.stringify()` it, but when I do, the 5th parameter (implemented in Google Chrome) - the error object - is represented with JSON like: `{}`

[image]

How to stringify it?

Answer (score 1):

`stack` is a lazily evaluated property. `(...)` means that the value is calculated via a getter, and only available when you explicitly access the variable.

If you want to get a sensible serialization of it, I suggest to extend `Error`'s prototype with a custom `toJSON` method. This method will then be inherit by `ReferenceError` and be picked up by `JSON.stringify` when you pass an instance of Error to it:

```
if (!Error.prototype.toJSON) {
    Error.prototype.toJSON = function() {
        return {
            name: this.name,
            message: this.message,
            stack: this.stack
        };
    };
}
```